# pip with several version of python on windows

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

So up untill now I had only one version of python : 2.7 x64.

Since I need to use a 32 bit libriry I installed python 2.7x32 in c:\python27x32, I call it in the command line usin "c:\python27x32

But how can I use pip to install new coponent for it? pip is somehow linked to my C:\python27 which contains the 64 bit version.

Thanks

Comment: Did you check your systems PATH variable?

Comment: Well the python 2.7 x64 is in the PATH variable, is it how pip is finding it?

Comment: Yes, because pip comes with Python (at least on Windows), so the pip.exe is located somewhere in the Python installation directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

enter :

```
c:\python27x32\Scripts\pip
```

instead of `pip`

Comment: oh pip has installed itself in the python path, allright, I always thought it was installed somewhere alone.

Comment: yes, and many packages (that have a cmd order) will be in the scripts folder, (PS: for py3 enter pip3 instead of pip)

Comment: oh, could I go into my python27x32 folder, rename python.exe to python32.exe, same for pip, add them to the path and then run python32 <script name> or pip32 <name> install afterwards?

Comment: @sliders_alpha , I am in ubuntu now, (not Win), but you can always try it :) .., (undo if any errors happen)